# Not able to get disqus comments secton on my website(jekyll)

Tags: jekyll, github-pages, disqus

I created my website on Lanyon, but while I was trying to configure the disqus comment box it did not appeared on the site.

I made following changes:

**_layouts/default.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-us">

  {% include head.html %}

  <body>
    {% include google_analytics.html %}
    {% include sidebar.html %}

    <!-- Wrap is the content to shift when toggling the sidebar. We wrap the
         content to avoid any CSS collisions with our real content. -->
    <div class="wrap">
      <div class="masthead">
        <div class="container">
          <h3 class="masthead-title">
            <a href="{{ site.baseurl }}/" title="Home">{{ site.title }}</a>
            <small>{{ site.tagline }}</small>
          </h3>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="container content">
        {{ content }}
        {% include comments.html %}
      </div>
    </div>

    <label for="sidebar-checkbox" class="sidebar-toggle"></label>

    <script>
      (function(document) {
        var toggle = document.querySelector('.sidebar-toggle');
        var sidebar = document.querySelector('#sidebar');
        var checkbox = document.querySelector('#sidebar-checkbox');

        document.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
          var target = e.target;

          if(!checkbox.checked ||
             sidebar.contains(target) ||
             (target === checkbox || target === toggle)) return;

          checkbox.checked = false;
        }, false);
      })(document);
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

**_includes/comments.html**

```
{% if page.comments %}
  <!-- Add Disqus comments. -->
  <div id="disqus_thread"></div>
  <script type="text/javascript">
      /* * * CONFIGURATION VARIABLES: EDIT BEFORE PASTING INTO YOUR WEBPAGE * * */
      var disqus_shortname = 'yathartha22-github-io'; // required: replace example with your forum shortname
      var disqus_identifier = "{{ site.disqusid }}{{ page.url | replace:'index.html','' }}"
      /* * * DON'T EDIT BELOW THIS LINE * * */
      (function() {
          var dsq = document.createElement('script'); dsq.type = 'text/javascript'; dsq.async = true;
          dsq.src = '//' + disqus_shortname + '.disqus.com/embed.js';
          (document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0] || document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0]).appendChild(dsq);
      })();
  </script>
  <noscript>Please enable JavaScript to view the <a href="http://disqus.com/?ref_noscript">comments powered by Disqus.</a></noscript>
  <a href="http://disqus.com" class="dsq-brlink">comments powered by <span class="logo-disqus">Disqus</span></a>
{% endif %}
```

These are the two files in which I made changes for disqus to integrate, but I an unable to get it. Can anyone please help me out. I even made `comments = true` in every post. Here is the [link](https://yathartha22.github.io) to my blog

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixing disqus comments include in `_includes/comments.html`:

```
{% if page.comments %}
<div id="disqus_thread"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
/* * * CONFIGURATION VARIABLES * * */
var disqus_shortname = 'yathartha22-github-io' ;

 /* * * DON'T EDIT BELOW THIS LINE * * */
 (function() {
   var dsq = document.createElement('script'); dsq.type = 'text/javascript'; dsq.async = true;
   dsq.src = '//' + disqus_shortname + '.disqus.com/embed.js';
   (document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0] || document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0]).appendChild(dsq);
 })();
</script>
<noscript>Please enable JavaScript to view the <a href="https://disqus.com/?ref_noscript">comments powered by Disqus.</a></noscript>
{% endif %}
```

Also in `index.html` change the way you generate the links to posts:

Change

```
  <a href="{{ site.baseurl }}/{{ post.url }}">
```

to this

```
  <a href="{{ post.url | absolute_url}}">
```

Disqus comments won't appear in the homepage posts list, but in each post, so inside each post you will see the comment box, e.g. here `http://localhost:4000/gsoc-preparation` or https://yathartha22.github.io/gsoc-preparation.